# How to open webpage in VBS

Tags: vbscript

My code is

```
Set WshShell = CreateObject("WScript.shell")
for i = 0 to 50
WshShell.SendKeys(chr(175))
next
Process.Start("CMD", "/C  start chrome.exe http://www.example.com")
```

It sets the volume to full, then opens chrome to example.com. But when I run it I get this error:

```
Cannot use parentheses while calling a Sub
```

How can I get it to raise the volume, and go to the webpage?

Comment: VB.NET <> VBscript.  Says so right in the tag text

Answer (score 4):

```
wshshell.run "www.youtube.com"
```

Comment: Please don't post only code as an answer, but also provide an explanation of what your code does and how it solves the problem of the question. Answers with an explanation are usually more helpful and of better quality, and are more likely to attract upvotes

Comment: No explanation perhaps, but in my testing this approach works and has the advantage of using the default browser.

Answer (score 3):

Try like this way :

```
Option Explicit
Dim URL,WshShell,i
URL = "www.yahoo.com"
Set WshShell = CreateObject("WScript.shell")
For i = 0 to 50
    WshShell.SendKeys(chr(175))
Next
WshShell.run "CMD /C start chrome.exe " & URL & "",0,False
```

Answer (score 1):

VBScript requires the CALL keyword when calling a sub with parenthesis. You can either write the code like this:

```
Set WshShell = CreateObject("WScript.shell")
For i = 0 To 50
    WshShell.SendKeys Chr(175)
Next
Process.Start "CMD", "/C  start chrome.exe http://www.example.com"
```

...or like this:

```
Set WshShell = CreateObject("WScript.shell")
For i = 0 To 50
    Call WshShell.SendKeys(Chr(175))
Next
Call Process.Start("CMD", "/C  start chrome.exe http://www.example.com")
```

Note: you don't get this error when calling a function and using its return value, like this:

```
Dim strTest
strTest = SomeFunction()
```

...because VBScript always requires the parenthesis when a function is used in an assignment.

Comment: The `Call Process.Start()` doesn't work :/

Answer (score -2):

This way works for me.

```
set wshshell = wscript.CreateObject("wscript.shell")
wshshell.run "chrome.exe https://stackoverflow.com"
```

You can change chrome.exe to whatever browser or the website to whatever you want

Comment: Is there something new in this answer that others didn't say?